# In Which file should I add `innodb_` related entries on MySQL V8.0

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, innodb

I want to increase following parameters for `mysql Ver 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M (default 96M)
innodb_thread_concurrency=25 (default 8)
max_connections=200 (default 100)
thread_cache_size=25 (default 10)
```

My `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` just have pointers to two other dir..

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

And

```
ls /etc/mysql/conf.d/
mysql.cnf  mysqldump.cnf
```

Where

```
ls /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
mysql.cnf  mysqld.cnf
```

Which file I should add those `innodb` etc entries?

Comment: Set these values in daemon command line firstly and ensure that this change makes sense.

Comment: I voted to migrate this question to dba.stackexchange.com. Stack Overflow really wants only questions about code problems, not DBA problems or install/config problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InnoDB options would only apply to mysqld, so I would put the options you show into `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.conf`, assuming that's the option file with a `[mysqld]` section.

But ultimately, all the option files will be read, and all options in the `[mysqld]` section, regardless of which file they appear in, will take effect.

So it's really up to you how you want to organize your own config. The only reason to separate the files is so you can find the options you're setting, or deploy different option files in different environments.

Comment: Suggest file name `z_Swapnil_Kotwal.cnf`  -- alphabetically last and shows who created it.

Comment: That's what `git blame` is for.